# ProFTPd MySQL query %u resolves to proftpd, not username

Tags: ftp, configuration, user-accounts, proftpd

I am trying to use ProFTPd's MySQL configuration to set up FTP login to my server. I have a `SQLNamedQuery` that is used to get the user info from the database (see [Setting up ProFTPd with default home directory based on username](https://serverfault.com/q/463160/68353)), and as part of the query I use the `%u` variable to insert the username. When I try to connect, I always get login incorrect. Checking the SQL log file, it seems that the login fails because `%u` is *not* being replaced by the username sent via FTP, but rather always by `proftpd`. Is there another variable I'm supposed to use? Why isn't `%u` being replaced by the FTP username? When I replace `%u` with a username that's in the MySQL user table, I can connect.

Here is my config:

```
<IfModule mod_sql.c>
        SQLLogFile              /var/log/proftpd/sql.log
        SQLDefaultUID           2001
        SQLDefaultGID           2001
        SQLBackend              mysql
        SQLPasswordEngine       on
        SQLAuthTypes            sha1
        SQLConnectInfo          *****@localhost ***** **********
        SQLNamedQuery           userinfo SELECT "uname, passwd, CONCAT('2001'), CONCAT('2001'), CONCAT('/var/projects/users/', uname) AS homedir FROM users WHERE uname='%u'"
        SQLUserInfo             custom:/userinfo
        SQLGroupInfo            ftpgroups groupname gid members
</IfModule>
```

And here is the relevant line in my SQL log file (notice the `uname='proftpd'` bit at the end):

```
query "SELECT uname, passwd, CONCAT('2001'), CONCAT('2001'), CONCAT('/var/projects/users/', uname) AS homedir FROM users WHERE uname='proftpd'"
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `%u` refers to the local user (which in your case is `proftpd`). You shoulduse `%U` (note the *capital* U), which refers to the FTP user. Note the last paragraph on [the ProFTPd SQLUserInfo page](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_SQLUserInfo.html), above "See Also".